# How to convert a binary number into a Signed decimal number

Tags: javascript, binary, decimal

I have a binary number something like this.. var data = "1100110010". 
I am trying to convert this into appropriate signed decimal number in Javascript.

The steps I use are following

1)  `var data = "1100110010";
     var bin2dec = parseInt(data,2).toString(10);`

The bin2dec gives the converted Decimal number as "818" .

But I want to access the signed decimal of the binary number too.

The signed decimal number for this binary code is "-206".

How can I access both signed and unsigned decimal Value from a given Binary Number. Please let me know . Any ideas would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some bit-shifting trickery

```
function uintToInt(uint, nbit) {
    nbit = +nbit || 32;
    if (nbit > 32) throw new RangeError('uintToInt only supports ints up to 32 bits');
    uint <<= 32 - nbit;
    uint >>= 32 - nbit;
    return uint;
}

uintToInt(818, 10); // -206
```

- Why `818`? Because this is the *uint* value of your *binary string*

  ```
  parseInt('1100110010', 2); // 818
  ```
- Why `10`? Because your signed int is represented by `10` bits in your *binary string*

  ```
  '1100110010'.length; // 10
  ```

Please note that for positive numbers, you can't just take `nbit = str.length;` as the string may not be `0`-padded, you'll need to know how many bits you're actually using

You may also want to throw an error for `uint > 4294967295`

---

For completeness,

```
function intToUint(int, nbit) {
    var u = new Uint32Array(1);
    nbit = +nbit || 32;
    if (nbit > 32) throw new RangeError('intToUint only supports ints up to 32 bits');
    u[0] = int;
    if (nbit < 32) { // don't accidentally sign again
        int = Math.pow(2, nbit) - 1;
        return u[0] & int;
    } else {
        return u[0];
    }
}

intToUint(-206, 10); // 818
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers..

I am getting the data from a hex code.. Is there any way I can find if the hex code is a signed decimal or a unsigned decimal.
and How to convert the hex code into the exact signed decimal

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to convert binary numbers to signed decimals using JavaScript's [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

```
const unsigned = 0b1111111100110010;
const [ signed ] = new Int16Array([0b1111111100110010]);

console.log(unsigned); // => 65330
console.log(signed); // => -206
```

I'm sure this will be less performant than bitwise operations, but it's certainly less code.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
var data = "1100110010";
var bin2dec = parseInt(data,2).toString(10);
var signed = (data.substr(0,1) === '1' ? '-':'+') + parseInt(data.substr(1),2);
```

This will give you -306 for the signed number. I am not sure if you had a typo in the number you indicated in your question (-206).

Probably not the best solution, but should work. You might still want to check the number of binary digits before deciding if it is signed.

Comment: This gives `-306` not `-206`

Comment: I know, i thought it was a typo in the question.

Comment: In `32` bits, `-206` is `11111111111111111111111100110010`, so it looks like OP has a `10` bit signed integer

Comment: You are right, if it is a 10 bit two's complement representation. I thought he is using the leading bit for the sign (i know it's not usual for most computer representations) and just had a typo in the number.

Answer (score 1):

Some other ways:

```
const bin = "1100110010"
const decimal = parseInt(bin,2)
const numBits = bin.length

let p = 0x80000000 >> (32 - numBits) 

console.log(p | decimal)
//or:
console.log(parseInt(bin.padStart(32,'1'),2) | 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will take an unknown bit pattern <= 32 bits and if it is < 8 bits convert to positive int and if >= 8 with a leading 1, a negative signed int.

The trick is to pad to 32 before parseInt

```js
const getSigned = binStr => parseInt(binStr.length >= 8 && binStr[0] === "1" ?
  binStr.padStart(32, "1") : binStr.padStart(32, "0"), 2) >> 0;

const signed = [
  "1100110010",   // -206
  "11111011",     //   -5
  "01111011",     //  123
  "1111111111000" //   -8
].map(getSigned);

console.log(signed);
```